# Python efficient pattern finding: regex v/s pattern in text?

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a simple case where I need to check for existence of a string (let us say `xyz`) in a `given_text`.

What will be a more efficient way to do so:

```
if 'xyz' in given_text:
    print 'found'
```

OR

```
import re
if re.compile('xyz').search(given_text):
    print 'found'
```

Comment: Use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

Comment: 1. It probably doesn't matter. 2. If you empirically determine that it does matter for your case, run some tests for real-world data. 3. `'xyz' in given_text` is probably much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone said, `in` is much faster

```
>>> timeit.timeit('"xyz" in "abcxyz"', number=10000000)
0.5210642332803808
>>> timeit.timeit('re.search(p,"abcxyz")', number=10000000, setup='import re; p=re.compile("xyz")')
15.548494171928667
>>> timeit.timeit('p.search("abcxyz")', number=10000000, setup='import re; p=re.compile("xyz")')
3.41808299957313
```

I think this is because `in` just have to look in the string. `regex` is a more complex tool that should be able to manage more complex cases so probably is slower because of the overhead to manage such complexity.

Comment: Do you know why that is the case?

Comment: And shouldn't it be `p.search("abcxyz")` or does `re.search(compiled_regex, string)` also reuse the compiled regex?

Comment: `p.search` is faster and I added in the example, thank you for pointing that out. I also added some sort of explanation.

Answer (score -1):

We can use python regular expression search module to get it done in efficient way.

```
import re
matchobj = re.search(r"xyz",given_text)
if matchobj:
   print "Found"
else:
   print "Not Found"
```